# Are you allowed to study (not Torah) on Tisha Bi'Av

Tags: halacha, books-generally, tisha-bav, secular-culture

For example if someone has a big math test on Yud Av, is he allowed to study math (my question was applied to math but goes to learning anything besides Torah) on Tisha Bi'Av?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62399

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sam said in the comments

"If it takes away someone's mind from aveilus then it should not be done,just like working on Tisha bav even after chatzos see Shulchan Aruch 554:22 with the Mishna Brurah there"

So since it most probably would take your mind off aveilus the answer is you are not allowed to.