# Does Judaism encourage secular learning?

Tags: secular-culture

Does Judaism encourage secular learning? Maths, Sciences: Biology, Chemistry, Automata Theory et cetera . . .

Comment: this might be too broad to answer. Not only would different individuals within Judaism present different answers, even the entity called "secular learning" is so broad that the answer would require breaking it down into many smaller parts.

Comment: I suppose I am looking to get a sense of the diversity of opinions. I'd be fine with an answer that presents differing/conflicting viewpoints. Actually I think that might be better.

Comment: Depends who you ask. Consisder Rav Hirch, Rav Schwab, Rav Breuer, the different answers from the various members of the Soloveitchi fasmily, the Vilna Gaon, ..... and all the many rabbonim and talmidei chachamim

Comment: Suggestion, based on a discussion in my synagogue a few weeks ago. We were discussing *Pirkei Avot* (Chapters of the fathers) and there are numerous adgaes that stress the importance of learning Torah and not wasting time. This seems to suggest that one should NEVER have ANY leisure. Perhaps, if you excerpt an idea from there and toss it into your question, it may narrow its focus.

Comment: "Does Judaism encourage secular learning?" In a word? No. In many more words, though, it may appear that Judaism does not *dis*courage such subjects, and it may also appear that Judaism may not consider such subjects to actually be "secular" under certain conditions.

Comment: One of these things is not like the others...

Comment: are you asking regarding earning a livelihood or just for curiosity or some other reason?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44185

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. If not consider clarifying which additional information you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You tell me.

> "The group comprises the religious people who understand the depth of
>   the Torah....Such people, who claim to be extraordinary; avoid
>   contemplation of the causes of phenomena and thereby are ignorant of
>   them, or most of them. Through intuition, or through Tradition, they
>   know of the existence of the First Cause, God. They believe that
>   thought and study of the channels He uses will lead them to deny His
>   involvement and the principles of His Torah, as occurred with the
>   heretical philosophers and their adherents. They (of this group)
>   believe that proper religious faith is the denial of secondary causes
>   and intermediate channels of God's actions.
>
> This leads them to remain ignorant of the laws of nature and to deny
>   facts observed by the intellect and experienced by the senses. They
>   believe that this is the requisite faith of the Torah and that only
>   through such faith can a servant of God properly rely on Him. **In
>   this way, they have earned the mockery and derision of the educated.
>   If a distinguished and learned Jew holds such a belief, I and any
>   fair-minded person consider that to be a desecration of God's Name
>   (hillul Hashem)...**"

Chapter 8 - Reliance of the Guide to Serving God by Rabbeinu Avraham ha Rambam
Translation: Raabi Yaakov Wincelberg

Comment: So he is saying that it is chillul HaShem to disdain/shun secular knowledge?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull Yep. But remember, we aren't talking about movie trivia secular knowledge or stuff like that

Comment: Thank you. This in particularly addresses something I was wondering about as I feel some people I know shun/disdain secular knowledge because they think it is a kiddush HaShem.

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull To each their own. i side with the Rambam and his son Rabbeinu Avraham. And maybe you should too :)

Comment: this was ~1000 years ago. the trials of the generation have changed

Comment: @ray But the stakes are higher now. The uneducated might not comprehend the damage we are doing to the earth, or how unsustainable eating the amount of meat we are eating is.

Comment: @ray Yet the authentic Torah way remains the same, b"H.

Comment: @ray Indeed the trials have changed. Nowadays we unfortunately have people claiming to be Gedolim who are actually in the category described in the quotation as desecrating God's name. All the more so nowadays must we emphasize proper education so that these pseudo-Gedolim don't manage to corrupt Jewish tradition.

Comment: @DoubleAA Amen.

Answer (score 2):

There are varying viewpoints about this subject today depending upon who you are learning from.

But generally, the 7 secular sciences are considered to be "novolot chochma", unripened wisdom. This is like is found in both Sefer Kol HaTur which is purported to be the teaching of the Vilna Gaon and can also be found in the teachings of the Maharal of Prague.

You can think of this in relation to the sulam, the ladder in Yaacov's vision at Beit El. The rungs of the ladder are different types of wisdom. Some are closer to the material, physical plane of existence and others are closer to the spiritual. The higher wisdom, the wisdom of the Torah is farther away from physical,  material existence. But in order to climb the ladder, you need to use all the rungs. You don't skip.

Having an initial and primary basis in holy studies is essential, especially for young children. But to have a mature understanding of the wisdom of the Torah, also requires broad knowledge of the secular sciences. They are complementary to each other.

This approach was also favored by Ramban who strove for practical knowledge of how things worked in order to properly grasp the decisions of poskim from earlier generations. That knowledge of how things behave in the physical plane of existence cannot be learned above. This was what G-d explained to the angels when they objected to Moshe taking the Torah from above to be given to the Jewish people. The angels have little or no connection to the physical. The Torah is intended to be used in the physical plane.

On a deeper level, Rabbi Yosef Gikatilla in Sefer Ginat Egoz relates this to the doubling letters in the Hebrew alphabet. There is nothing that exists in the material world that doesn't have its root and source above. This "fractal" kind of relationship is derived from the doubling letters. Knowledge of both, the upper wisdom and the lower wisdom gives complete and mature understanding.

Comment: "The rungs of the ladder are different types of wisdom" are you using this episode as usefull imagery to convey an idea, or are you saying that this is actually the significance of the episode. If the latter, do you have any sources?

Comment: "This approach was also favored by Ramban who strove for practical knowledge of how things worked in order to properly grasp the decisions of poskim from earlier generations." I have seen a lot of his writings, but have never seen him doing this. Have a source?

Comment: "This was what G-d explained to the angels when they objected to Moshe taking the Torah from above to be given to the Jewish people. The angels have little or no connection to the physical. The Torah is intended to be used in the physical plane." However one interprets that Midrash, all we see is that mitzvos are physical acts which angels are by definition excluded from. Where do we see anything about secular learning?

Comment: No idea what you are talking about in the last paragraph.

Comment: Thank you. I feel like this provides a good way of thinking about it. What are the '7 secular sciences'?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55433/759

Comment: @mevaqesh try these: רבי הלל ריבלין תלמיד הגר״א, ספר קול התור: פרק ה: חלק ב, חיים מחוולוזין, נפש החיים: שער א, סוף פרק י, אור החיים: בראשית ו:ה ד״ה וייצר כו״, כלי יקר: בשלח: טו:יז, רמבן: כתבי רמבן דפוס מוסד הרב קוק: תורת ה״ תמימה: קנה ד״ה ודבר ברור הוא כו״, מהר״ל מפראג: ספר נתיבות עולם: נתיב התורה פרק יד ד״ה ודבר זה בארו חכמים, רבנו בחיי: פרקי אבות: ג:ח״י ד״ה ודבר ידוע כי שבע חכמות כו״

Comment: @mevaqesh And regarding your comment concerning the reference to Sefer Ginat Egoz, try learning it. You might get a lot from that classic. It's in print and wonderful to learn.

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull How they are broken out exactly varies depending on the source you're looking at. But the general list is: mathematics, astronomy, geometry, chemistry, biology & physical sciences, medicine, logic, grammar & syntax, music, engineering, and psychology & brain sciences.

Comment: Looks like an amazing collection of sources in that comment. What do they say? At the minimum, which comment are they addressing?

Comment: What are doubling letters? Like medial/final forms? Degeishim Chazakim?

Comment: The doubling letters are בג״ד כפר״ת. They either take a dagesh or do not. The dagesh carries an implication of gevurah. In addition, this is the source for the many implications of the paradigm of seven that appears throughout the Torah. Shabbat, shemittah, yovel, etc.

Comment: @mevaqesh the sources are addressing your first three questions/comments.

Answer (score 1):

Of course!

Genesis 1:26 states,

> “Let us make man in our demut." Verse 1:27 relates that “G-d made man
>   in His tzelem, in the tzelem of G-d, He made him.”

Thus, people are made in the image of G-d, in the tzelem. It cannot mean “likeness" since G-d has no body and is one. Onkelos renders 2:7's “a living being,” to ruach m’mal’la, “one with the power of speech,” a characteristic of man's intelligence. Maimonides also felt that this denotes intelligence, interpreting the "Garden of Eden" story to be a parable about using one's intelligence. Thus, Maimonides considered it a mitzvah to study science.[1]

In his introduction to book 2 of the Guide, Maimonides states that:

> “A man should never cast his reason behind him, for the eyes are set
>   in front, not in the back.”

and

> "The truth is the truth no matter the source."

Thus, he had no quarrels accepting the philosophy of the Greek pagan Aristotle.[2]

Additionally, Ben Zoma said:

> "Who is wise? He who learns from all men, as it is written (Psalm 119:99) “I have gained understanding from all my teachers.”

[1] Guide 1:1 and 3:27 and Mishnah Torah, Sefer HaMada, Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah, chapter 2

[2] See introduction to the Guide

Comment: Chazal also stated 'Who is wise? He who learns from anyone (and anything)' or something along the lines. Might even learn a thing or two from your worst enemies.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your comment. I will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pirkei Avot 3:18:

> רבי אליעזר בן חסמא אומר, קנין ופתחי נדה, הן הן  גופי הלכות .תקופות
>   וגמטריאות, פרפראות לחכמה.
>
> Rabbi Eliezer ben Chisma says: the laws of *Kinin* [bird
>   offerings] and *Niddah* [menstruation], these are the body of the
>   laws. **Astronomical calculations** and *Gematria* [numerical
>   calculations] are the condiments to wisdom.

Here, "astronomical calculations" is not the greatest translation. What is meant is according to commentary Bartenura, is the orbit of the planets and constellations. In a sense, it is part of astronomy.

Gematria refers to the art of using the numerical equivalence of the Hebrew letters (*Aleph* = 1; Tav = 400, etc.) and figuring out how a word has the same numerical equivalent as another word. Obviously, this does involve basic "mathematics", in terms of being able to count.

As for math, in particular, we see numerous places in Tana"ch were counting and percentages are used, so, knowing that area of math is necessary to be able to perform mitzvoth.

Getting back to this adage, Rabbi Eliezer calls these two fields "condiments". This term is used in comparison to the beginning of the adage that discusses the two things that are essential (basics) of Torah laws. The last two are "extras" because, according to [Ikar Tosfot Yom Tov](http://www.sefaria.org/Ikar_Tosafot_Yom_Tov_on_Pirkei_Avot.3.18.6?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all), these items (planet movements and gematria) helps one's heart be drawn to appreciate G-d's wisdom. See the rest of the commentary for a more detailed explanation of this concept.

I can't state, per se, whether math and astronomy would be considered "secular" in this concept. But, based on Rabbi Eliezer's teaching it appears that it was encouraged then, and he seems to encourage a knowledge of these areas now.

Answer (score -3):

if it's necessary for earning a livelihood then obviously yes.

if it's necessary for one's mental balance as some kind of outlet then perhaps and depends to what extent.

if it's just to kill time then no.

consult with LOA. many factors involved and each person is different.

Comment: Sources? Why should we take your word for any of this?