# Is a jew allowed to learn secular studies and science?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, science

Is a jew allowed to learn secular studies and science?
Is there a prohibition against learning any secular subjects and/or science?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62399/15256

Comment: [also related](/q/18669)

Comment: Pirkei Avot (forgot exactly where) mentions the importance of learning geometry and some other "secular" subjects. That and some basic algebra are actually necessary. Geometry e.g. needed for building a succah. Algebra for calculating ma'aser and other percentages and fractions for example. Also, obviously some form of astronomy was needed all along for blessing the New Moon.

Answer (score 3):

Let me summarize it for you in one sentence:
**It's not about what you learn, it is about why you learn it.**

- If you learn science to help you with the understanding of Halachic topics, or for observing Mitzvot, or for making your living - it is not only allowed but necessary and obligatory.
- If you learn for to stray away from the Jewish tradition or things that will drag you from the path of the just - you are strictly forbidden to do so.

Comment: Please provide sources of any sort, otherwise you will continually get downvoted by the community!! (Not to mention that your answer is not useful for someone who does not trust your expertise in Judaism...)

Comment: Most people don't science learn for either of these reasons but to gain knowledge and the a ability to think critically about subjects of study that differ from Torah. Also for the reason of having knowledge which goes towards earning parnossa.

Comment: @Dude It all boils down to either pro-Torah or cons-Torah. Each one has to decide for himself. You are right, most people are so self-unaware they don't spend much time thinking of it. The last one I addressed in the answer.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I addressed it in Meta that I don't intend to spend hours finding sources and formatting my answer for a new guy who spends a minute for a question. For a general question - there's a general answer. If the question was about different Shitos I would bother mentioning sources. I proposed we sort the questions into categories like novice, good advanced or Rabbis :) to understand the desire level of answers.

Comment: Al berko. This isn't about someone being unaware but simple not having those as reasons for their studies. This answer doesn't completely answer the question but only addresses two very specific reasons for such a study.

Comment: @AlBerko What about if someone knows that his answer is correct without having another source? If he had published it in an article online, it would be ok for anyone to quote that as a source, and noone would have any meta issues with it, so why can't anyone offer his own knowledge as a source?

Comment: @alberko you are allowed to continue to produce poor quality posts. Your announcing your intention to do so doesn't make them better. (Seems like a waste of your time.)

Comment: @ribbis he can post without sources, it will just not be of much value. If you link to a random anonymous blog that will also be of little value. The goal is to be well sourced, not just sourced somewhere.

Comment: A Jew should study the secular sciences because having knowledge of the natural world will not allow atheist to ridicule holy truths. It is also best for society and educates the students. Maimonides advocated for the advancement of science in health and study. Not to mention the fact that most Jews accept the theory of evolution since Adam and Even is described as a metaphor.

Comment: The Rambam wrote, "the only path to knowing G-d is through science—and for that reason, the Bible opens with a description of the creation.”